# On Android 11, audio is not playing for other apps while my app is connected to a Bluetooth speaker mic

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

My application allows for users to transmit and receive audio, similar to a walkie talkie. Much like a walkie talkie, there is not always audio being transmitted/received, and we handle the audio focus as appropriate. Users are able to do this using both the phones built-in speaker + mic, and Bluetooth connected devices which provide speaker or mic. On Android 11, whenever my app is active while a Bluetooth device is connected, audio from other applications does not play.

As an example, say the user is using my app with a Bluetooth speaker mic connected. They are able to correctly receive (hear) my app audio through the Bluetooth device, and transmit (speak) audio through the Bluetooth device. However, if they attempt to play audio from another app, like say a video on YouTube - the video plays but the audio does not come through; either through the Bluetooth device or the phone speaker.

This incorrect behavior is new to my app on Android 11; audio works properly on prior versions of Android. Likewise, audio works properly when there is no connected Bluetooth audio device; other app audio plays as expected through the phone speaker when my app is not receiving/transmitting audio.

In my research into this issue, it appears there are some long-standing issues with Bluetooth on Android 11, with regards to both Android Auto and audio devices generally. My app utilizes the AudioManager SCO states to determine when an audio device is connected, and I suspect that a change in Android 11 related to this area is the culprit.

I haven't found many programmatic discussions about this issue, so if anyone has any ideas or suggestions about things to try, I would be most appreciative. Thanks for your time.